# How do I Convert a List to Complex parameter array

Tags: c#, arrays, web-services, multidimensional-array

I have my own service reference that I am calling with a named List<>.  This list converts properties that are terribly named into something useful.  How can I pass this List back in a way where it will understand it?

I am getting the data back from the Client, but I don't know how to initialize it to be sent to a different web service in a way that it is expecting it.

The terribly named parameter generated by .NET:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("p2PARM", Order=4)]
    public P2PARM[] p2PARM {
        get {
            return this.p2PARMField;
        }
        set {
            this.p2PARMField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("p2PARM");
        }
    }
```

Its properties generated by .NET as well:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34230")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://update_data/xsd")]
public partial class P2PARM : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string p2A0STField;

    private string p2A5TXField;

    private decimal p2G9NCField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public string p2A0ST {
        get {
            return this.p2A0STField;
        }
        set {
            this.p2A0STField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("p2A0ST");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
    public string p2A5TX {
        get {
            return this.p2A5TXField;
        }
        set {
            this.p2A5TXField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("p2A5TX");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=2)]
    public decimal p2G9NC {
        get {
            return this.p2G9NCField;
        }
        set {
            this.p2G9NCField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("p2G9NC");
        }
    }
```

I can successfully pull data down into dataList:

```
List<Models.UpdateData.InputData.Data> dataList = input.DataList;
SVC_UpdateData.P2PARM[] p2Input = new SVC_UpdateData.P2PARM[dataList.Count];
```

This is where I was attempting to set the variables, but p2Input is null and I couldn't figure out where to go next..

```
for (int i=0; i < dataList.Count; i++)
{

    p2Input[i].p2A0ST = dataList[i].NamedField1;
    p2Input[i].p2A5TX = dataList[i].NamedField2;
    p2Input[i].p2G9NC = dataList[i].NamedField3;
}
```

Here is the XML of the WSDL that I am sending to:

```
  <xs:complexType name="P2PARM">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="p2A0ST" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="p2A5TX" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="p2G9NC" type="xs:decimal" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Here is my Model which contains my list:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class InputData
    {
        [DataContract]
        public class Data
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string NamedField1 { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string NamedField2 { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public decimal NamedField3 { get; set; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public List<Data> DataList { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p2Input` is not null, it's an array and you initialized it. But you also need to instantiate each element in the array:

```
for (int i=0; i < dataList.Count; i++)
{
    p2Input[i] = new SVC_UpdateData.P2PARM();
    p2Input[i].p2A0ST = dataList[i].NamedField1;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I will mark this as the answer because you did answer the question correctly.  However, I way over-thought this.  I changed my code to be a List<UpdateData.P2PARM> and populate it like normal and then when I set it I set it as p2Input.ToArray() and it works beautifully.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sure, you can do that too. I would argue that an array is theoretically more efficient, but it probably doesn't matter in this case.